# Heroku: Uncaught Error: Component auth has not been registered yet

Tags: reactjs, heroku, shopify-app

I have a Heroku hosted React Shopify app. The app works when I run it locally but when I push to Heroku I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Component auth has not been registered yet
    at $G.initialize (index.1fd486fb.js:264:2094)
    at new F0 (index.1fd486fb.js:4612:309)
    at Kte.t.INTERNAL.registerComponent.dr.setServiceProps.ActionCodeInfo.Operation.EMAIL_SIGNIN [as instanceFactory] (index.1fd486fb.js:4657:170)
    at $G.getOrInitializeService (index.1fd486fb.js:264:2812)
    at $G.getImmediate (index.1fd486fb.js:264:730)
    at qq._getService (index.1fd486fb.js:459:770)
    at t.<computed> [as auth] (index.1fd486fb.js:489:853)
    at Object.h [as auth] (index.1fd486fb.js:489:729)
    at index.1fd486fb.js:4657:1214
initialize @ index.1fd486fb.js:264
F0 @ index.1fd486fb.js:4612`your text`
Kte.t.INTERNAL.registerComponent.dr.setServiceProps.ActionCodeInfo.Operation.EMAIL_SIGNIN @ index.1fd486fb.js:4657
getOrInitializeService @ index.1fd486fb.js:264
getImmediate @ index.1fd486fb.js:264
_getService @ index.1fd486fb.js:459
t.<computed> @ index.1fd486fb.js:489
h @ index.1fd486fb.js:489
(anonymous) @ index.1fd486fb.js:4657
```

I've tried deleting and reinstalling the node packages. Any ideas help, thanks!